# Why does the menu jquery UI widget have a weird name?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I couldn't locate this question - I'll give it a go.

I was looking through some jQuery UI widgets and I noticed a usage of a function name that I have never seen before. I am curious as to why this convention was used.

I have never seen a stringed selector used as a function name before. Why are they using this method?

```
"mousedown .ui-menu-item > a": function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
},
"click .ui-state-disabled > a": function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
},
"click .ui-menu-item:has(a)": function( event ) {
```

Comment: What widget was this?

Comment: menu widget. I updated the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could have been using it as a map and/or using jQuery's [.delegate( selector, eventType, handler(eventObject))](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

```
var funcMap = {
    'foo': function(e) {
        console.log('foo');
    },
    'bar': function(e) {
        console.log('bar');
    }
};

funcMap['bar']();
funcMap['foo']();
```

Comment: awesome.. let me look into that. I never seen that convention before - had me stumped. thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

This is attaching event handlers to the events

The strings you see are the event names + selector, a string which is probably split internally and uses the selector somehow